# How to process multiple SASS maps at once?

Tags: css, function, sass, flexbox, maps

**I'm trying to create utility classes dynamically.**

Within SASS it's possible to define a map, and then use at `@each` to generate classes based on the map's `key` and `value`. However, the css `property` needs to be added manually within the `@each`. I would like a function which can add that element and some naming conventions based on the map's data. So, based on the below example, I would like to add `flex-direction` dynamically, instead of having to create an `@each` for each map.

**What works**:

```
//Example Map
@flex-wrap: ("nw": "no-wrap", "w": "wrap", "wr": "wrap-reverse")

//Example @each
@each $name, $value in $flex-wrap
    .flx-w-#{$name}
        flex-direction: #{$value}
```

**What I need**:

```
.flx + $prefix + $name
    $property: $value
```

**And the expected compiled css result**:

```
.flx-d-w {
    flex-direction: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dynamical way to do what you want is to use nested maps, two `@each` loops and a mixin.

```
$flex-direction: (
  "name": "flex-direction",
  "prefix": "flx-d",
  "values": (
    "r": "row",
    "c": "column",
    "rr": "row-reverse",
    "cr": "column-reverse"
  )
);

$flex-wrap: (
  "name": "flex-wrap",
  "prefix": "flx-w",
  "values": (
    "nw": "nowrap",
    "w": "wrap",
    "wr": "wrap-reverse"
  )
);

@mixin createClasses($maps...) {
  @each $map in $maps {
    $propertyName: map-get($map, "name");
    $propertyPrefix: map-get($map, "prefix");

    @each $value, $key in map-get($map, "values") {
      .#{$propertyPrefix}-#{$value} {
        #{$propertyName}: #{$key};
      }
    }
  }
}

@include createClasses($flex-direction, $flex-wrap);
```

With the the example above you will get:

```
.flx-d-r {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flx-d-c {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flx-d-rr {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.flx-d-rc {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.flx-w-nw {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.flx-w-w {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flx-w-wr {
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
```

The "magic" part here is using the spread `...` operator to pass any number of maps you want in the mixin ([documentation here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#taking-arbitrary-arguments)). You only have to call it once with all your maps and it will create all your classes.

---

SASS version of the code:

```
$flex-direction: ("name": "flex-direction", "prefix": "flx-d", "values": ("r": "row", "c": "column", "rr": "row-reverse", "cr": "column-reverse"))
$flex-wrap: ("name": "flex-wrap", "prefix": "flx-w", "values": ("nw": "nowrap", "w": "wrap", "wr": "wrap-reverse"))

=createClasses($maps...)
  @each $map in $maps
    $propertyName: map-get($map, "name")
    $propertyPrefix: map-get($map, "prefix")
    @each $value, $key in map-get($map, "values")
      .#{$propertyPrefix}-#{$value}
        #{$propertyName}: #{$key}

+createClasses($flex-direction, $flex-wrap)
```

Comment: Thank you!

That solves the `@each` portion that I was struggling with, but is it possible to plug that into a function that will process all of my maps, therefore not having to write an `@each` for each map?

Comment: @Evenheavy Do you mean for another map than one for the flex properties?

Comment: I eventually wanted to create utility classes for multiple things. Padding, Margin, Animations, etc. Flex is just one part of it. I know about `map-merge`, would that be helpful?

Also, don't worry about writing the examples in sass, scss is fine.

Comment: @Evenheavy Okay I am on it, do you prefer nested maps (`$flexProperties`) or each properties (`$flex-wrap`, `$flex-direction`...) in a separated map?

Comment: I would prefer each section, such as `flex-wrap`, `flex-direction`, in their own map if possible. I just need to understand the syntax and logic. I'm new to SASS.

Comment: @Evenheavy Please see my updated answer. If there is something you don't understand tell me. :)

Comment: I think I got it. I had tried the mixin approach, but I didn't understand how to define the variables for prefix and property. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Evenheavy I realized that we can even simplify the prefixes part by storing a single string such as `"prefix": "flx-d"` and then call it with `#{map-get($map, $prefix)}`. Then the `$mapPrefix` variable is not required anymore. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I've added that change to my own code. Thanks again!